# Fix Windows partition from Linux environment

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows

I have a Windows machine. About two months ago I installed on a separate hard drive the Windows q4os distro.

Now suddenly Windows can't manage to boot anymore, and the automatic repair tool isn't able to fix the problem. I tried from recovery cmd in windows, but it says that the drive is write-protected.
Linux is unable to mount it and diskpart in Windows says it isn't write-protected. Event system restore can't do it
I have really important files on Windows that I can't lose. If I start notepad from cmd in windows repair environment I can manage to access those Files, but I'd really prefer to not manually copy everything and then reinstall Windows. 
Is there something I can do from Linux? Thanks

Comment: Could you give more details on your setup please? 1. Which version of Windows was the main one before you added the other HDD and installed q4os on it? 2. Do I understand correctly that since it's a Windows machine, you're running Linux from a live media like CD / DVD / USB? 3. What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I think at the time I installed q4os, Windows was on the 21H2 release, but I can't get more information right now. Q4os is installed in dual boot, on a separate drive. If you go on q4os site, on the download page you'll found the windows editions, that is the same as a normal build, but can be installed in the same windows drive and partition. I had another hdd so I installed it there, but I could have installed it in the C drive alongside Windows